# ERROR 1452 (23000) does not print the line number in the data file sourced

Tags: mysql

I am importing data dump and I get the error as below. Is there a way I could get the line number in the source file which caused this?

```
mysql> source datadump.sql;
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ...
```

To add, I dont see the error messages in logs.

Thanks..

Comment: Do you get the line number if you use `mysql < datadump.sql` from the shell, instead of using `source` from the `mysql>` prompt?

Comment: That approach usually wouldnt print any message. But it worked now, prints the line number! Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I've deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `source` command from MySQL Monitor, use the `mysql` command directly from the shell:

```
$ mysql < datadump.sql
```